# Getting an error when calling a method from another class

Tags: php

```
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
class USER {

  function send_mail($email,$message,$subject) {

    require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
    $mail->Host       = "mail.smeinfratech.co.za";      
    $mail->Port       = 465;             
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Username="datalogging@smeinfratech.co.za";  
    $mail->Password="********";            
    $mail->Send();

  }
}
```

That's the first class and then I want to call the send_mail method in the following page

```
initVariables();

$userEmail = 'blank';
$SYSID = 'blank';
$SYSTEM = 'blank';
$userID = 'blank';

echo($userEmail);
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
require_once 'class.user.php';

$user = new USER();

$user->send_mail("dataloggingtest@smeinfratech.co.za", "TEST", "TEST");
```

The $user = new USER(); line causes my page not to load.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `require_once 'class.user.php';` puts me off a bit. Is the file really named `class.user.php`?

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Yes, not my code, taking over from someone else in the company xD

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the main script and then the exact error message that php outputs. Also as far as I see `class USER` serves no real purpouse, as it contains a single function and no data at all. The code can be modified to send emails without creating `USER object` in the main script. I see no viable reason for existance of `class USER` at this point. Looks looks like someone was really misinformed when creating this email sending.

Comment: There are a lot of other functions in the USER class, I just didn't include them. Same goes for the second class. It just gives me a blank page that says 'blank'. That text is most likely from one of the variables declared.

Comment: I think I will look for a way to use that send_mail function outside of the USER class. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: At this point it's hard to tell without more code. Blank page does not mean that page wasn't loaded. Maybe it's supposed to be blank? I am afraid a deeper code analysis is required, and this can take a week or more. Digging through someones code, especially when you have no Docs in any form is not fun at all.

Comment: I suggest you contact the person that you took over from and ask to give you some idea about Site structure and what Framework was used when writing the site. If a framework was used at all?

Comment: Hi @THCHydra, If your code is just a send_mail function, the system will not show any message or anything. You can try printing some message on success / failure. So, you can get to know if you are getting the code run properly.